# Openshift Routers: Should they be exposed for applications?

Tags: openshift, router

I have two openshift routers, running as pods, running in OSE.

However, I don't see any associated services in my openshift cluster which forwards traffic / loadbalances to them.

Should I expose my routers to the external world in a normal OSE environment?

Note that this is in a running openshift (OSE) cluster, so I do not think it would be appropriate to recreate the routers with new service accounts, and even if I did want to do this, it isn't always gauranteed that I will have access inside of OpenShift to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the haproxy routers which are a part of the OpenShift platform, and which handle routing of external HTTP/HTTPS requests through to the pods of an application which has been exposed using a route, then no, you should not at least expose then as an OpenShift *Route*. Adding a *Route* for them would be circular as the router is what implements the route.

The incoming port of the haproxy routers does need to be exposed outside of the cluster, but this should have been handled as part of the setup you did when the OpenShift cluster was installed. Exactly what you may needed to have done to prepare for that when installing the OpenShift cluster depends on your target system into which OpenShift was installed.

It may be better to step back and explain the problem you are having. If it is an installation issue, you may be better asking on one of the lists at:

- https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo

as that is more frequented by people more familiar with installing OpenShift.